# Knitr for Scrollbar in r studio

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

Basis [How to add horizontal scroll bar for a ggplot plot in RMarkdown html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52448104/how-to-add-horizontal-scroll-bar-for-a-ggplot-plot-in-rmarkdown-html) answer, i tried to add a vertical scrollbar in the gantt chart in R studio, but i am getting the following errors :-

````
 <style>
Error: unexpected '<' in "<"
>   .superbigimage{
Error: unexpected '{' in "  .superbigimage{"
>       overflow-y:scroll;
Error: object 'overflow' not found
>       white-space: nowrap;
Error: object 'white' not found
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
> 
>   .superbigimage img{
Error: unexpected symbol in "  .superbigimage img"
>      max-width: none;
Error: object 'width' not found
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
> 
> 
> </style>
Error: unexpected '<' in "<"
> 
> 
> 
> <div class="superbigimage">
Error: unexpected '<' in "<"
> 
> ```{r plot_it , echo = FALSE, fig.width=20,fig.height=3}
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
> p
> ```
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
````

Below is the code i have used :-

````
 ---
 title: "Untitled"
 output: html_document

 ---

 ```{r}
p <- ggplot(df, aes(colour= Timeline.Type, group = System.Lease.ID))  +  
     geom_segment(aes(x=Timeline.Start, xend=Timeline.End, y=System.Lease.ID, yend=System.Lease.ID), 
     size=3) +
     labs(x="Timeline.Start", y="System.Lease.ID", title="Project timeline") +
     scale_color_manual(values=actcols, name="Project component") 


     ```
     <style>
          .superbigimage{
              overflow-y:scroll;
              white-space: nowrap;
          }

          .superbigimage img{
             max-width: none;
          }


        </style>



        <div class="superbigimage">

        ```{r plot_it , echo = FALSE, fig.width=20,fig.height=3}
        p
        ```
````

Please help me knowing that how can i correct this to have a vertical scrollbar in the gantt chart,

Thanks !!

Comment: you need to add </div> at the end, also you should indent you code carefully when adding html. try running every chunk alone to get precisely where is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did add </div> and re-ran code in chunks, now i am getting the error of Error: unexpected '<' in "<" for the line <style>

Comment: is there any other better way to build a scrollable gantt chant using R-studio ?

Comment: I am sure it is going to work if you take take of your white spaces. I think it is a bug in Rstudio. Make sure nothing is highlighted is a suspected manner. The area of the chunk should be distinctive while the all the html should appear as normal markdown text except for the curly braces should be colored according to your theme.